# how to include jdbc jar in spark using maven

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, sbt

I have a spark (2.1.0) job that uses the postgres jdbc driver as described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

I'm using the dataframe writer like

```
val jdbcURL = s"jdbc:postgresql://${config.pgHost}:${config.pgPort}/${config.pgDatabase}?user=${config.pgUser}&password=${config.pgPassword}"
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", config.pgUser)
connectionProperties.put("password", config.pgPassword)
dataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(jdbcURL, tableName, connectionProperties)
```

I'm successfully including the jdbc driver from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.1.jar downloading it manually and using `--jars postgresql-42.1.1.jar --driver-class-path postgresql-42.1.1.jar`

However, I'd prefer to not have to download it first.

I've unsuccessfully tried `--jars  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.1.jar`, but that fails from

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$Client$$distribute$1(Client.scala:480)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Client.scala:600)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Client.scala:599)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.foreach(ArraySeq.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11.apply(Client.scala:599)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11.apply(Client.scala:598)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:598)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1154)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1213)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I have also tried:

including `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.1"` in my `build.sbt` file

`spark-submit` options: `--repositories https://mvnrepository.com/artifact --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1`

`spark-submit` options: `--repositories https://mvnrepository.com/artifact --conf "spark.jars.packages=org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1`

these each fail the same way:

```
17/08/01 13:14:49 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:446)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy JDBC  jar file to `jars` folder in `spark` directory and deploy your application with `spark-submit` without `--jars` option.

Comment: Cool, this works. I'd still prefer to have it self contained in the project (so I can distribute my jar and run-command without requiring setup), but this is better than what I had going.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the driver option like you do user and password with the JDBC class.